# saving values of an array plus values of other variables holds reference to it into the harddrive

Tags: c#, variables, storing-information

I have a `byte[] array` from a bitmap.
I could save it to a file via:

```
File.WriteAllBytes("path&fileName", byte[]arrayName);
```

There are other variables that reference this `byte[] array`, such as its name, its original location, etc.
In short, how do I collectively save data or group a few variables into a set for the sake of saving bitmap reference values?

```
(data = byte[], name=string, loctionX = int, locationY = int, Width=int ....etc)
```

Does this task belong to the database field only or is there another way?
For example, can I use XML or linq? (I am trying to guess) (:
I'm trying to avoid involving databases (SqlDatasource connection ...etc) in my project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should declare a POCO for the values you want to store and serialize it. For example:

```
public class Foo {
    public byte[] Data {get;set;}
    public string Name {get;set;}
    public int LocationX {get;set;}
    // ... etc
}
```

Now pick any serializer; XmlSerializer, DataContractSerializer, protobuf-net, BinaryFormatter, JSON.NET - any would do; and use that to read/write the instance from/to disk. For example:

```
Foo obj = ...
using(var file = File.Create(path)) {
    var ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Foo));
    ser.Serialize(file, obj);
}
```

Comment: I'll google some more on XmlSerializer, DataContractSerializer, protobuf-net, BinaryFormatter.. thanks a lot